# can I run multinomial logistic regression in R with data on SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, r, sql-server-2008, logistic-regression, multinomial

I have a very large dataset on MS SQL server management studio. Now I want to run a multinomial logistic regression (call it MLR) on R using that dataset, but I cannot sqlFetch or sqlQuery the data first (because it is too large). Is it possible to write something in R that run a MLR without pulling data from SQL first,i.e. can I run MLR in R on SQL data? Thanks.

Comment: Certainly not in base R, which works on objects in RAM. Perhaps using the `bigmemory` or related packages. Or perhaps via Rev-R

Comment: How long does it take to do `sqlFetch` or `sqlQuery` on the data?